# Unable to map database to POJO using hibernate in netbeans 13 (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: hibernate, pojo, netbeans-plugins, ubuntu-22.04, netbeans-13

I am using Netbeans-13 with Ubuntu-22.04 and trying to map a database with some POJOs in my spring project using hibernate plugin available in netbeans. But in the mapping wizard, I am unable to select hibernate configuration file/ hibernate reverse engineering configuration file as they are not listed in the drop-down menu.
How to resolve this issue?

New Hibernate Mapping Files and POJOs from Database:

[image]